# Java - Regex to get if word contains all letters of another one

Tags: java, regex

Is it possible to create java regex that could define if one word (*base*) contains all letters from another word (*sample* frow which regex is created) exactly?

For example

**Input**: *base* = 'Subexpressions', *sample1* = 'Nubs'
**Output**: `True`

**Input**: *base* = 'Subexpressions', *sample2* = 'Expert'
**Output**: `False`

Explanation: *base* contains all letters from *sample1* but doesn't contain 't' from *sample2*.

Comment: Why is a regular expression a requirement?

Comment: @Duncan It necessary for making code concise and clear like `base.matches(createRegex(sample))`. without iterations over base and sample words indices.

Comment: Well... if you're going to hide complexity within method names, then you can do all the iteration you like and call it `containsAll(base, sample)`. I suspect the resulting regular expression will be challenging to read and thus harder to maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a regex approach, here's how you could do it programmatically.

1. Make a list of letters: `Subexpressions` => subexprion
2. Build a series of lookaheads with the letters, and anchor it: `^(?=.*s)(?=.*u)etc(?=.*n)$`
3. Run that regex against the string. It will act as an AND, because the lookaheads check one by one if a letter is present in the target string. If you have a match, bingo.

Of course, running `strstr` 10 times (once for each character) also works.

**Note:** Some engines may report strangely for a zero-width match, so for safety you can add a single dot after the lookaheads, ensuring that you have at least one char in the match:

```
^(?=.*s)(?=.*u)etc(?=.*n)$
```

You don't care about the char, just about whether there is a match at all.

Comment: Thanks. Slightly modified the solution works fine for me: `(.*)(?=.*s)(?=.*u)etc(?=.*n)(.*)`

Answer (score 1):

This problem doesn't really need regex. Just use this simple approach:

1. Set a boolean variable `found` to `true`
2. Iterate `sample` variable character by character
3. Check presence of each character in your `base` string variable
4. Set `found` to false if a character is not found and bail out of loop

Comment: What other options do you have to make it fast?